# Remove publishing capability from user IDs

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to remove the capability of users other than the administrator/superadmin (ID number 1) to add a page, I know that there are plugins which you can edit the wordpress role but in my case I need it to be per user/username/userid (no plugin that I no of is available)..

Currently user number 2 needs to be 'Administrator' because a specific plugin I use only displays reports to 'Administrator' role but I need to remove add page capabilities. I have the following code:

```
function modify_capabilities()
{
global $userdata;
get_currentuserinfo();
  $userdata->ID != 1 ->remove_cap('publish_pages');

 }

add_action('admin_init','modify_capabilities');
```

But it doesn't work.. The error is in this line:

`$userdata->ID != 1 ->remove_cap('publish_pages');`

Comment: And what does `$userdata->ID != 1 ->remove_cap('publish_pages');` line supposed to do? Which object's `remove_cap()` method you're invoking?

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems off by a bit:

```
function modify_capabilities()
{
global $userdata;
get_currentuserinfo();
    if ($userdata->ID != 1) {
         $role = get_role('author');
         $role->remove_cap('publish_pages');
         $role->remove_cap('publish_posts');
    }
 }

add_action('admin_init','modify_capabilities');
```

Updated based on your comments and taking the original details from the blog you linked to. Not sure why you removed those parts though...

Comment: this is the original code (I just modified it): $editor_role = get_role('editor');
  $editor_role->remove_cap('publish_pages'); from here: http://erisds.co.uk/wordpress/spotlight-wordpress-admin-menu-remove-add-new-pages-or-posts-link

Comment: I also get this error when i tried your code: Fatal error: Call to a member function remove_cap() on a non-object on this line: `$somevariable->remove_cap('publish_pages');`

Comment: Like I said, you need to change `$somevariable` to be the *correct* variable. From your other comment it looks like it needs to be `$editor_role` but you'll need to make sure that you have initialised the `$editor_role` variable.

Comment: hmm.. the reason why I didn't use $editor_role because it's not the editor role that I want to remove the capability.. I wanted to remove the capability to users that don't have 1 as their user ID.. I hope I explained it well...

Comment: That's why I changed it to `author` (see my edit). This obviously will only work for people creating pages/posts. That post you linked to also spoke about removing Menu items per user, which perhaps would be a better way?

Comment: Okay the updated code doesn't give an error but whenever I go to the 'Add New' page.. i'm still able to publish posts and pages.. hmm not sure why